# Invoking the google function with concurrent request receiving error

Tags: google-cloud-functions, serverless

Description: I created a small google cloud function which executes a small job in nodeJs. On top of that I created go utility which sends a http request to the cloud function. After the function is not in cold state.

Issue: On sending 25 concurrent request I see two issues

1. In the logs there is a latency for the function receiving the request. (I am on a high bandwidth internet connection)
2. Frequently receiving the below error:

   `<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en>\n  <meta charset=utf-8>\n  <meta name=viewport content=\"initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width\">\n  <title>Error 502 (Server Error)!!1</title>\n  <style>\n    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}\n  </style>\n  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>\n  <p><b>502.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>\n  <p>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>`

There are no warning or errors on the function logs.

Comment: When you say latency, how high is the latency in terms of s or ms? Is it less than a second, or maybe several seconds? Also, you are saying that you do not see errors in the logs for the Cloud Function. Where do you see these error that you presented?

Comment: Each function execution time is 2-5 second. However, that varies based on the request on the function. In this case I am sending a request that would take 2-5 second for execution. The latency is 5-10 seconds on average. If the the request is larger and the processing time is a minute. In that case 4 functions execution start and then it gets put in the queue is what I realize. The errors are received when I am posting a HTTP request to the function.

Comment: I read the google documentation 500 error is received when the quota limit is reached. However, I am not sure what is causing the latency in processing these request in concurrent.

Comment: When you say latency, do you mean latency between the initialisation of the HTTP request and the initialisation of the Cloud Function or latency between the initialisation of the Cloud Function and the response of the Cloud Function? It would be great if you provided code of your Cloud Function so that it would be possible to test it and investigate.

Comment: I received a response from the Google Team through a support ticket. The root cause of the issue was the environment tends "over queue" rather than "over provision" new instances in case of spikes in request. This is usually not the case under standard load. Would probably have to wait until Google releases the Google Functions and fixes their optimizations.